# Matlab Syntax for Symbolic Solving

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a symbolic equation equation like

`i = 1:n (i=1...n)` it takes random values.

G_i = B_i + C_i * D_i  and I have B_i, G_i C_i and D_i equaling to some constraints.

I have to simplify a such equation through matlab.

I used 'syms' to define each symbol but I don't know how to define that 'i' indices.

Also, my second question is if I want to change it to summation format (symsum) where i=1...n how can I write the code for to simplify given some constraints. Any example can be useful for me to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is create an array of symbolic values: [Matlab docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) show how to do this for A, I'll leave it up to you to do the rest.

```
A = sym('A',dim)
```

Then you could do something like:

```
G(i)=b(i)+c(i)*d(i)
```

Comment: Thank you first of all. So, what I'll do basically is define each symbol such as G = sym('G', [1 n]) and same thing for B, C and D.

Comment: Let me also add that A = sym('A',dim) code doesn't work for Matlab R2009b or lower version. Symbolic Math Toolbox should have a version higher than 5.4